# how to sync music volume with ring volume using AudioManager

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager

here is my code:

```
   if(setting.getBoolean("autoVolume",false))
     {       
         setVolume(c,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));  
         Log.e("max ring volume",manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)+"");//result:7
         Log.e("max music volume",manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)+"");//result 15
     }
```

setVolume function:

```
     private void setVolume(Context c,int streamName,int volume){

     AudioManager manager =
             (AudioManager) c.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     manager.setStreamVolume(streamName,volume,0);
 }
```

i want sync music volume with ring volume but it doesn't work because they haven't same range(max music volume is 15 and max ring volume is 7!)

i want a simple math way
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have numbers `x` in the range `[a,b]` and you want to transform them to numbers `y` in the range `[c,d]` you need to do this:

```
y = ((x−a) * (d−c) / (b−a)) + c
```

In your case:

- `x`: ring volume
- `[a,b]`: 0-7
- `[c,d]`: 0-15
- `y`: music volume

You get:

```
music_volume = ring_volume * (15 / 7)
```

Comment: thanks,is it possible that y be a float number?(float number gives error for setting volume)

Comment: then, simply use `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` or simply a cast to int on y. But do the computation in floats !

Comment: thanks again,can i use this ?:int i=maxMusicVol/maxRingVol;//2.5
// set music volume to ringVolume*i